# Adding more value to class to filter

Tags: javascript, html

This is my main script, that filters div by checkboxes

```
function change(){
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox');
    var chekboxInputs = Array.from(checkboxes).map(a => a.querySelector('input'));
    var allAreUnselected = chekboxInputs.every(function(elem){
       return !elem.checked;
    });
    if(allAreUnselected){
       chekboxInputs.forEach(function(input){
          Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("." + input.getAttribute("rel"))).forEach(function(item){
              item.style.display = 'block';
          });
       });
    }
    else {
      chekboxInputs.forEach(function(input){
          Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("." + input.getAttribute("rel"))).forEach(function(item){
            item.style.display = input.checked ? 'block' : 'none';
          });
       });
    }
}
change();
```

This is my html file. In this html there are checkboxes and dives

```
<div class="filter">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" rel="canada" onchange="change()"/>Canada</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" rel="china" onchange="change()"/>China</label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="result">
    <div class="canada">
         <h1>Canada</h1>
         <h2>Jason</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="china">
         <h1>China</h1>
         <h2>Ni</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

But the script filters only one value(in my case - city). How can I add another filters to class of div. For example

```
<div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" rel="india" onchange="change()"/>India</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" rel="programming" onchange="change()"/>Programming</label>
</div>
```

by the adding another value to class

```
<div class="india programming">...</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are looking for. Adding the class should do the trick. What is the problem?

Comment: I want to add more filters. For example for one div I want to add india and programming. But when I write <div class="india programming">...</div> script is not working, when I write <div class="india">...</div> script is working because class has only one value (india). If I add more than one, filter is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding multiple CSS classes could work, but your current code will overwrite a previous setting of `style.display` making it sometimes go from `none` to `block`, even though the `none` setting was the right setting.

Here is the code you could use, based on the first example you gave, and an additional result that has both classes "canada" and "china":

```js
function change(){
    let results = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.result > div'));
    // Hide all results
    results.forEach(function (result) {
        result.style.display = 'none';
    });
    // Filter results to only those that meet ALL requirements:
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.filter input[rel]:checked'), function (input) {
        const attrib = input.getAttribute('rel');
        results = results.filter(function (result) {
            return result.classList.contains(attrib);
        });
    });
    // Show those filtered results:
    results.forEach(function (result) {
        result.style.display = 'block';
    });
}
change();
```

```html
<div class="filter">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" rel="canada" onchange="change()"/>Canada</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" rel="china" onchange="change()"/>China</label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="result">
    <div class="canada">
         <h1>Canada</h1>
         <h2>Jason</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="china">
         <h1>China</h1>
         <h2>Ni</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="canada china">
         <h1>China and Canada</h1>
         <h2>Ni Jason</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that I assume the `rel` attribute can only reference one CSS class.

Comment: I have turned the code in my answer into a snippet which you can run. What is not working for you? What do you get? Errors?

Comment: Thank you, very much. I understood) +1

Comment: Please edit your question and be *precise*. Give an example, and what you expect from it. It is not clear to me what you are saying here. What are the *exact* requirements for a result to be visible or not?

Comment: I need to make filter, which will specify. For example
in my case, If I choose canada and china, it will be shown only one div(which has a class china canada), another will be hiden, because their class hasn't class china canada. Could I explain my issue?

Comment: Please add this important information to your question. There are several ways to interpret "filter". I have now updated my answer.